# prevent urlRouterProvider.otherwise

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am passing a really long url to view2. But my `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` is taking over and bringing me back home. How do I prevent `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` from executing for view2?

```
.state('nav.view2', {
    url: '/view2/:url',
    views: {
        'games-tab': {
            templateUrl: 'src/views/view2.html',
            controller: 'view2'
        }
    }
})

.controller('view1', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $state) {
    $scope.open = function(googleUrl)
    {
        $state.go('nav.view2', {url: googleUrl});
    }
})
```